# How to provide code for updating multiple columns with JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am developing a java application that is working with a MySql database. This is going to be used by a colleague of mine, as an external jar.

My problem is that they need to update certain columns of the table. Is there a way to provide a method where they could choose which column they want to update?

The alternative I know is to create a different method for each column, having for example

```
Update.updateName(String name);
Update.updateAge(int age);
....
```

That would take a lot of effort to write, since there a more than 20 columns available.

**EDIT**

Ok, it seems that I wasn't clear :)

Update is just a class that handles the database update. Nothing of importance really.

So, to rephrase, I need a way to handle updates to a table with multiple columns.

My code is going to be used by others, so I need a way to use some method that would "force" them to choose a column (or a number of them) from the available columns, instead of letting them insert as free text.

Let's say I have a table like so

```
name    varchar(50)
age     int(3)
address varchar(300)
```

If I just had these three columns I would do

```
public class Update{
  public void updateName(String name,int id){
     //connect to mysql and update name
  }

  public void updateAge(int age,int id){
     //connect to mysql and update age
  }

  public void updateAddress(String address,int id){
     //connect to mysql and update address
  }
}
```

and my colleagues would do

```
Update update =new Update();
update.updateName("newName",1);
update.updateAge(20,1);
.....
```

As I mention before, that would take alot of effort, because of the size of my table. Is there a way to "load" the column names on my code and allow the user of the jar library to choose one from that list? (since this is a library it will not be executed in advance in order to get the names from the database)

Comment: The definition of JDBC ResultSet allows updates using the column names ([ResultSet javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)). I am not sure I understand your question?

Comment: @RudolphEst look like JDBC is completely abstracted away given that generic 'Update' class example. But now I have to guess because this question is really lacking in details.

Comment: @Gimby - I think your guess is probably accurate (I assumed the same). I was hoping the OP would clear up the question a little. Describing more of what the `Update` class **is**.

Answer (score 3):

If this is how you want to do it, I suggest using an `enum` for each column name. I.e.:

```
public enum ColumnName {
    FistName("first_name"), LastName("last_name");

    private String columnName;

    private ColumnName(String name){
        this.columnName = name;
    }

    public String getColumnName(){
        return this.columnName;
    }
}
```

And have the method `Update.update(ColumnName cn, String value)` where you replace the inner code with something like:

"UPDATE TableName SET " + cn.getColumnName() + " = " + value + " WHERE ..."

Hope this is clear and helps.

Comment: Side note: creating the query like that is an SQL injection risk. There is a reason why PreparedStatement exists.

Comment: That looks promissing, but as @Gimby notices, is there a way to "force" the user to use one of the predefined column names? which i would get from the metadata on demand from the database.

Comment: @Gimby yes I agree, but there are enough libraries to use around this issue, just showed the hardcoded query as an illustration for simplicity

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg If that is all you want to do then nobody can stop you, but keep in mind that Stack Overflow favors correctness over simplicity. You may trigger downvotes if you willingly and knowingly leave in SQL injection problems in answers.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understand you question, I hope the following code may help.

```
public void updateTableColumns(){
    Connection c = DBConnection.getConnection(); //Connect with SQL DateBase
    String sql = "update tableName set column1 = ? , column2 = ? , column3 = ? where rowName = ?";  //Create a SQL sentence 
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(sql); 
        ps.setString(1, "Value of column1");// Set value for each ?
        ps.setString(2, "Value of column2");
        ps.setString(3, "Value of column3");
        ps.setString(4, "Value of rowName");

        ps.execute(sql); //execute the sql sentence in sql database
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If your want columnName flexible, your can use String concate make columnName to a variable. – george970 1 min ago

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The following illustration may help you.

```
public SomeClass{
    //select the columns for update and add them into a List.
      selectedColumnList.add(columnNames);
    //insert values for columns to update in another List.
      valuesToUpdateList.add(values);
}
```

and then you can execute the query mentioned below

```
String columns=selectedColumnList.get(0)+"='"+valuesToUpdateList.get(0)+"'";
for(int i=1;i<selectedColumnList.size();i++){
    columns = columns+","+selectedColumnList.get(i)+"='"+valuesToUpdateList.get(i)+"'";
}
String query = "UPDATE table_name SET columns WHERE something='some value';"
```

I hope it may help you, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the right way to go, but it worked for me, so I would like to hear your ideas as well.
First I created a class that would hold the names of the columns

```
public class ColumnNames {

    String column;
    public String getColumn(){      
        return column;
    }

    public ColumnNames name(){
        column = "name";
        return this;
        }
    public ColumnNames status(){
        column = "status";
        return this;
        }
    public ColumnNames url(){
        column = "url";
        return this;
        }
    public ColumnNames postalCode(){
        column = "postalCode";
        return this;
        }
.....

}
```

then I created a class that would handle the updating process.

```
public class Update {
/**
     * A class containing the column names and the new values
     */
    class UploadData{
        private ColumnNames column;
        private String value;

        public String getValue(){
            return value;
        }
        public String getColumnName(){
            return column.getColumn();
        }
        UploadData(ColumnNames column,String value){
            this.column=column;
            this.value=value;
        }
}
    //An array List that would hold the column title and the value 
    List<UploadData> uploadDatas=new ArrayList<UploadData>();
    public void addItem(ColumnNames column,String value){
        uploadDatas.add(new UploadData(column,value));
    }
    public List<UploadData> getItems(){
        return uploadDatas;
}
}
```

Then set the values I want to update

```
Update up =new Update();
up.addItem(new ColumnNames().name(), "Name");
up.addItem(new ColumnNames().status(),"active");
up.addItem(new ColumnNames().postalCode(),"xxxxx");
.....
```

And update the table using these values
update(up);

```
public boolean update(Update up){
        Connection conn = null;

        String updateTable="update table set ";
        for(int i=0;i<up.getItems().size();i++){
            updateTable+=up.getColumnName(i)+"='"+up.getValue(i)+"' ";
            if(i<up.getItems().size()-1){
                updateTable+=", ";
            }
        }
        updateTable+=" where ...";
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_ADDRS,DB_USER,DB_PASS);

            boolean result=conn.createStatement().execute(updateTable);
            try{conn.close();}catch (Exception e1) { /* ignored */ }
            return result;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            try{conn.close();}catch (Exception e2) { /* ignored */ }
            return false;
        }
}
```

Since this is working, is there a reason I SHOULDN'T use it like that?

Thanks